# How to add an imageView on a tableView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I am developing iOS App.

I would like to add a `UIImageView` to a `UITableView`.

I am writing down the following code, however the `UIImageView` is behind the `UITableView`.

Probably I think that after loading `UITableView` data, `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.imageView];` should be implemented, however I have no idea how to do.

Could you tell me solutions?

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240,100,77,77)];
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hoge"];
    [self.view addSubview:self.imageView];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
     return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:  (NSInteger)section
{
     return 100;
 }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

{
     // Usual TableViewCell process
}
```

Comment: do you want to put a table view on a image view and make the table view transparent so that you can see the image?

Comment: if you add an image view on a table ,you cannot see the table cells which you don't want to be like that!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set background for tableview with image view you can set like that in viewDidLoad:

```
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
```

Comment: I would like to add imageview on tableview(not tableview cell). And I think your former answer is the imageview hides behind the tableview!

Answer (score 0):

It is not so clear but you could try either directly:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

or

```
UIImageView *imv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,2, 20, 25)];
imv.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"hoge.png"];
[cell addSubview:imv];
```

or if you want to add an image as a background:

```
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hoge.png"];
 self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
```

Comment: it is not clear that the author wants to add the image to table view or to table cell. What do you say? @ilyasUyanik

Comment: Yes I agree. That is why I provided an answer what mostly asked.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to add the image on table view!(not tableview cell)

Comment: You want to add an image to the background?

Comment: No I want to add an image above tableview.

Comment: Ok, that is what you are looking, background image which I have provided in my answer. Try it and see it how it looks like.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply! However , the imageview is not background of tableview. it is above tableview.

Comment: @szakira  you mean that, You need to bring the image view above the table view once cells are getting loaded? If not. Please specify at which point yo need the image view to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want one element (Image view or table view) to be visible at a given time one approach can be -

```
[myView insertSubview:[self tableView] belowSubview:[self imageView]];
```

Another approach can be (assuming you add tableview and image view on top of a view) -

```
int tableViewIndex = [[self.view subviews] indexOfObject:[self tableView]];
[self.view insertSubview:[self imageView] atIndex: tableViewIndex];
```

One more -

```
[[self view] insertSubview:[self tableView] belowSubview:[self imageView]];
```

Simple one (alternative to your idea)-

```
[[self view] sendSubviewToBack:[self tableView]];
```

Comment: Thank you , but above methods do not go well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;` where headerview is your image in a `UIImageView`

Comment: Thank you , but it doesn't goes well.

Comment: Can you provide more details about what is not going well